# MySQL subquery does not give me the highest value with MAX or ORDER BY LIMIT 1

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

I have problems with my MySQL query. Its subquery does not give the highest value of `last.id`.

```
SELECT rounds.winners, rounds.losers
FROM players
INNER JOIN teams ON teams.id = players.ilmo_id
INNER JOIN status AS first ON first.id = players.status_id
LEFT JOIN matches ON matches.chart_id = 12
  AND matches.id = (
    SELECT  last.id
    FROM    matches AS last
    WHERE   (last.player1_id = players.id
            OR last.player2_id = players.id
            OR last.player3_id = players.id
            OR last.player4_id = players.id)
            ORDER BY last.id DESC
            LIMIT 1
        )

 JOIN charts ON charts.id = matches.chart_id
 JOIN places ON charts.template_id = places.template_id AND places.id = matches.place_id
 JOIN templates ON places.template_id = templates.id
 JOIN rounds ON places.round_id = rounds.id
 WHERE players.comp_id = 12
```

I also have tried this way, but this does not work:

```
SELECT rounds.winners, rounds.losers
FROM players
INNER JOIN teams ON teams.id = players.ilmo_id
INNER JOIN status AS first ON first.id = players.status_id
LEFT JOIN matches ON matches.chart_id = 12
  AND matches.id = (
    SELECT  MAX(last.id)
    FROM    matches AS last
    WHERE   (last.player1_id = players.id
            OR last.player2_id = players.id
            OR last.player3_id = players.id
            OR last.player4_id = players.id)
        )

 JOIN charts ON charts.id = matches.chart_id
 JOIN places ON charts.template_id = places.template_id AND places.id = matches.place_id
 JOIN templates ON places.template_id = templates.id
 JOIN rounds ON places.round_id = rounds.id
 WHERE players.comp_id = 12
```

**Edit:**

Here is the latest version which seems to work OK.

```
SELECT rounds.winners, rounds.losers
FROM players
INNER JOIN teams ON teams.id = players.ilmo_id
INNER JOIN status AS first ON first.id = players.status_id
LEFT JOIN matches ON matches.chart_id = 12
  AND matches.id = (
    SELECT  last.id
    FROM    matches AS last
    WHERE   last.chart_id = 12 /* modified */
            AND (last.player1_id = players.id
            OR last.player2_id = players.id
            OR last.player3_id = players.id
            OR last.player4_id = players.id)
            ORDER BY last.place_id DESC /* modified */
            LIMIT 1
        )

 JOIN charts ON charts.id = matches.chart_id
 JOIN places ON charts.template_id = places.template_id AND places.id = matches.place_id
 JOIN templates ON places.template_id = templates.id
 JOIN rounds ON places.round_id = rounds.id
 WHERE players.comp_id = 12
```

Comment: Almost certainly asked and answered thousands of times before, but if still struggling, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What are you joining matches to?  The on clause looks more like the conditions of a where clause.  You're joining matches where chart_id = 12 and it's the highest id but in your subquery, you're not referencing chart_id.  It's returning the highest ID of all chart_ids.  So if the highest ID row does not have a chart_id = 12, the on clause won't match.

Comment: @LAS Now my subquery has `WHERE last.chart_id = 12 AND (last.player1_id`... OK?

Comment: Yes, I see now.  I don't think you need matches.chart_id = 12 immediately after the ON.  That's redundant as It's handled in the subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT rounds.winners, rounds.losers
FROM players
INNER JOIN teams ON teams.id = players.ilmo_id
INNER JOIN status AS first ON first.id = players.status_id
LEFT JOIN matches ON matches.id = (
    SELECT  max(last.id)
    FROM    matches AS last
    WHERE   last.chart_id = 12 /* modified */
            AND (last.player1_id = players.id
            OR last.player2_id = players.id
            OR last.player3_id = players.id
            OR last.player4_id = players.id)
        )
 JOIN charts ON charts.id = matches.chart_id
 JOIN places ON charts.template_id = places.template_id AND places.id = matches.place_id
 JOIN templates ON places.template_id = templates.id
 JOIN rounds ON places.round_id = rounds.id
 WHERE players.comp_id = 12
```

Comment: Do you think that `max(last.id)` is better than using `order by` with `limit 1`?

Comment: Only because it's standard across platforms.  But I'd use the syntax that gives the best performance.